# RewriteCond to check if a specific Query String does not exist in the URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need help in writing a RewriteCond to check if a specific `QueryString` does not exist in the URL.

If a specific string "`?nvi`" does not exist then only should I redirect the URL.

Below Rule is what I have written but it does not work:-

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(.*nvi.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

But the above rule fails even when the URL has string "`?nvi`" in the URL(`www.text.com?svi`).

Please help me write rewritecond which will redirect to a new URL only when the "`?nvi`" string does not exist in the requested URL.

Comment: If you really mean *redirect* (as in external redirect) you should use the `[R]` flag. You are currently doing an internal rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^nvi [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php? [L]
```

`?` in the end will strip down existing query string.

Comment: You can also use the QSD flag to remove the query string:

RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,QSD]

Comment: QSD flag didn’t exist before Apache 2.4